# Edited question is shown for the review to the same Editor

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

An edited question (just removed `tag`) on StackOverflow, later was shown to the same user for `review`.

If a user edits a question and *same edited question* is shown to him for reviewing, he will always accept it.

*Is there any specific reason for this behavior?*

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079729/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files-for-image-upload) was the question i edited and the one shown to me while `reviewing`

Comment: _"If a user edits a question, and his edited question is shown to him for reviewing, he will always accept it."_ Not necessarily. If I edited spam into that question and you got it for review, would you approve it? You weren't approving _your_ edit, you were reviewing someone else's edit. Worse, you _approved_ their edit _undoing_ your previous edit- They added the Android tag back in.

Comment: @Kendra i think you misunderstood what i said. I edited the question and i got MY EDIT for review (I was reviewing the content that i just edited). If you edit spam, it becomes YOUR EDIT, not MY EDIT which is not the case we are talking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a misunderstanding.

You edited the post at 6:28 UTC to remove the Android tag from the post in question. Five minutes later, at 6:33 UTC, another user *suggested* an edit to add the tag back in. The edit [you reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14003977) was theirs, not yours.

As a user with more than 2,000 rep, your edits are applied automatically and don't get reviewed. Your edit didn't even hit the queue. The other user's edit, however, did need reviewed and you happened to be the first person to get it.

We can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40079729/revisions) that your edit didn't have to be approved, as your edit does not have a link to its review. The other user's edit does.

[image: Revision history]

Looking at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40079729/timeline) also shows us that there was only one edit review for this question, and it was not your edit.

[image: Timeline view]

If *your* edit had been the one in review, it would have been listed after the review, as a suggested edit is only applied after it has been approved. Your edit wasn't suggested, though. It was directly applied to the post due to your reputation privileges.

It takes 2,000 rep to edit directly, and it takes 2,000 rep to review. Very rare should be the situation where you are able to review with a suggested edit in the queue. You would have to suggest an edit and hit 2,000 rep before the edit had been approved or rejected. Stack Exchange very likely already has measures in place to ensure a user does not review their own edit, even though this is an edge case.

Comment: That makes sense now.

Comment: I'm impressed both at the question asked and the answer given (in a positive way)